# Existing OnsenUI working on Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, onsen-ui

I already done a OnsenUI project using notepad++ but i dont know how to compile into an android apk, after some research i found that i can use OnsenUI with Visual Studio. So i downloaded all extensions and components for getting start with OnsenUI in VS but now i need to know how to import my project in VS and compile into my new android app.
 Already Added Existing Item but when i go test only open firefox and i cant compile it.. 
Any solutions?

Question2: When i start a new OnsenUI project BLANK and hit RUN/TEST button, im getting few errors, and all my extensions folders are set correctly.. Its because i cant run a BLANK project with doing nothing?

Thanks, sorry for my bad english

@edit

[IMAGE: errors when try to build blank onsenui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGDug.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Monaca CLI.

You can develop with Visual Studio Code (which is free, and separate from Visual Studio 2015)

You debug by running the Monaca Preview command (outside Visual Studio) and then every change is shown in the browser. (Best to use Chrome). Click on F12 for debugging. (You can set the chrome debugger to show as if its a phone and choose different layouts (for iphone or android).  Your onsenUI will show correctly for each chosen phone.

To make an APK follow the monaca instructions. (You'll need a developer account on android and on IOS). See here: https://community.onsen.io/topic/557/build-apk-using-monaca-cli-or-cordova-cli